# Foreach skip first

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I'm using a foreach to get a serie of 5 images. The first one of the serie needs to be large and the rest as thumbnails.

How can I get this working?

Currently using following code:

```
    <img src="shop/nike/shirt/pwp_green-detail_01.jpg" class="img-responsive full-width">                           


                    <?php 
                        get_multi_images_src('medium','full',false,id); //4 accepted parameters : the 1st size (STRING) & the 2nd size (STRING) & thumbnail (BOOLEAN) & id (integer)
                    ?>


                    <?php $imgs  = get_images_src('');
                    foreach( $imgs as $i )
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="' . $i[0] . '" class="img-responsive full-width">

                            </div>
                          </div>';
                    ?>
```

Comment: Change $i[0] to $i[1]

Comment: Changing to [1] won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to find the first element in a foreach loop and skip it

```
<?php $imgs  = get_images_src('');
                    foreach( $imgs as $i )

if ($i !== reset($imgs)) {
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="' . $i[0] . '" class="img-responsive full-width">

                            </div>
                          </div>'; 
                      }
else      {
 echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="' . $i[0] . '" class="some-otherclass">

                            </div>
                          </div>'; 


}
                    ?>
```

Comment: Great, now I have 4 of 5 images.. but how do I fetch the first one and add a div to it?

Comment: @rwzdoorn Your first image is in $i[o] so just add a div to it

Comment: Your edit broke the script. When I use $i[0] I'm getting image 2 till 5 (4 in total). When using $i[1] it breaks.